# Flutter apk Issue

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk, release

I am using Providers for this Project and non_null safety. what happens when i make apk (*using this command flutter build apk --split-per-abi*) and install it in my physical device the first page works as expected but the next pages don't work accouringly. i am using localization as well when i change the language the app works fine.

There is no such error in the logs that is why i don't understand it. the second screen is like it doesnot refresh while apis brings data at 200.

I've tried almost all solutions from stackOverflow and gitHub etc..
Some are Listed Below:

1. Internet Permission
2. --no-shrink
3. fat apk (flutter build apk --release)
4. upgrading gradle downgrading gradle signing the apk
5. proguard-rules.pro
   etc....

this is not the first time apk is not working properly. if you can help me I'd be greatful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your not using null safety you should execute the following command

```
  flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-sound-null-safety
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it, didn't work.